# How can i set key and vector when doing encryption?

Tags: c#, encryption, aes

I am using the following code. The key and vector are copied from the web. No secrets there.

```
    private static byte[] key = { 123, 217, 19, 11, 24, 26, 85, 45, 114, 184, 27, 162, 37, 112, 222, 209, 241, 24, 175, 144, 173, 53, 196, 29, 24, 26, 17, 218, 131, 236, 53, 209 };
    private static byte[] vector = { 146, 64, 191, 111, 23, 3, 113, 119, 231, 121, 221, 112, 79, 32, 114, 156 };
    private ICryptoTransform encryptor, decryptor;
    private UTF8Encoding encoder;

    public SimplerAES()
    {
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        encryptor = rm.CreateEncryptor(key, vector);
        decryptor = rm.CreateDecryptor(key, vector);
        encoder = new UTF8Encoding();
    }
```

Can someone explain what's the meaning of the settings for key and vector. I would like to privately code up the way my data is encrypted but I am not sure where to start.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "Privately code up the way"? Code up a few helper functions? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is simply your encryption key, the passphrase that someone needs to decrypt the data. AES is a symmetric cipher, so the same key will be used both for encryption and decryption.

The [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) (IV) is a technical detail: when using a [block cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher) in [CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29), the ciphertext for each input block depends on the ciphertext for the previous input block (and also on the current input block and the key, of course). However, when trying to encrypt the *first* block there is no "previous" data to take into account; the IV takes the place of the ciphertext for the "0th" input block in this case.

In practice, this means that when decrypting, it's also **necessary to know the IV in addition to the key**. However the IV is not sensitive information, and you can simply store it along with the ciphertext (thus making the key the only information you need to decrypt that you do not already have).

**Note:** It's good practice to *not use the same IV multiple times*; you can simply generate a random one each time you need to encrypt something.

Comment: just as an addition: CBC is not the only mode that uses IVs, but the IV always provides the "0th" block

Comment: @DarkSquirrel42 - What do you mean by "the IV always provides the "0th" block" ?

Comment: @JennyK: He means that the IV always plays the part of the "current state" of the cipher when it starts up, before it encrypts the 1st block (because at that point there is no "real" previous state).

Comment: @JennyK: He is referring to the various formulas for the modes that need an IV. For example CBC mode: C_n = E_k(P_n + C_{n-1}), where E is the block cipher, k is the key, C is the ciphertext and P is the plaintext. The first block of cipher is thus C_1 = E_k(P_1 + C_0) by the formula. But what is C_0 (the "0th" block)? By definition it is the IV.

Comment: Great description. Does this mean that IV could be likened to a hash salt in that it is none sensitive data that must be known for decryption?

Comment: @Hawxby: Kind of, because you can still decrypt all blocks except the first without the IV. Also, mishandling (reusing) it has worse consequences that reusing a salt. That's because a reused salt only tells the attacker that they can amortize a rainbow table attack while a reused IV in CBC mode (*the mode matters!*) leaks information about the first plaintext block (assuming in both cases that the attacker has access to salt+hash or IV+ciphertext respectively).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following sites should help.

[Encryption 1](http://www.obviex.com/samples/Encryption.aspx)

[Encryption 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndael.aspx)

[Encryption 3](http://weblogs.asp.net/plip/archive/2004/07/06/173797.aspx)